# unity render a movie as quickly as possible

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity to create movies. Right now, I create a scene and play it and record it in real time and export the video file. But I'd like render the scene as fast as possible and reduce the time for creating the movie.

How can I render simple scenes faster than real time in Unity? For example, if I have a 10-second movie at 24 frames/second and my machine can render 240 frames in a second, I'd like to finish the job in a second rather than wait for 10 seconds. Working with framerate and time might do the job but I was wondering if there is a better/simpler way to do it.

Unreal Engine's [capture movie](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/AnimatingObjects/Sequencer/Workflow/RenderAndExport/RenderMovieSettings/) renders simple scenes faster than real time without me changing anything and I'd like to know if there is something similar in Unity.

Update: You can [disable Cap FPS](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/working-with-unity-recorder?uv=2019.4#6000f436edbc2a3c53b3d807) to speed up rendering if you are using the Unity recorder. I am using something else because I want to record the video in a Unity build.

Comment: [Application.targetFrameRate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html) might be what you're looking for

Comment: Could you tell us how exactly you are rendering currently? If your device can do 240 frames per second then Unity would render 240 frames per second ... the question is what are you doing within those frames? You could e.g. simply not do it in `Update` but have a "manual" method that behaves the same and call it yourself ... In general the Time.timeScale is what affects the global replay velocity of a Unity scene

Comment: Thank you both. I am rendering simple 2d animation. I ended up setting Time.timeScale = 3.0f and Application.targetFrameRate = 90 for 30 FPS animation. My computer is rendering the animation three times as fast this way.